# Correct way to use _viewstart.cshtml and partial Razor views?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using [**_viewstart.cshtml** to automagically assign the same Razor Layout](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx) to my views.

It's a dead simple file in the root of my Views folder that looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

This is more DRY than adding the @Layout directive to every single view.

However, this poses a problem for Razor **partial** views, because they run the contents of _viewstart.cshtml and therefore incorrectly assign themselves a layout, which makes them, um, no longer partial.

Here's a hypothetical project, showing the _viewstart.cshtml file, the shared _layout.shtml file, and a partial view ("AnonBar.cshtml").

[image: Example project structure]

Currently, the way that I'm getting around this is by adding the following line to every partial view:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
```

This seems like the wrong way to denote a view as a partial in Razor. (Note that unlike the web forms view engine, the file extension is the same for partial views.)

Other options I considered but that are even worse:

- Putting all partial views into a common folder, so they could share a common _viewstart.cshtml. This breaks the convention of views being in the same folder as their controller.
- Not using partial views.

Is this something that is still being fleshed out by the Razor view engine team, or am I missing a fundamental concept?

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but what are those icons next to the filenames? :) Some kind of source-control right?

Comment: @jitbit: VisualSVN

Answer (score 240, accepted):

If you `return PartialView()` from your controllers (instead of `return View()`), then `_viewstart.cshtml` will not be executed.

Comment: Aha, did not know about the `PartialViewResult` class. That was what I needed.

Comment: As a follow-up, I've found that I need to **also** explicitly set the return type of the action method to `PartialViewResult` instead of the usual `ActionResult`.

Comment: @Portman are you seeing issues when the action method's return type is not `ActionResult`? I'm surprised that this is an issue because the MVC runtime should not behave any differently in this case (i.e. as long as the type returned by the action method is `ActionResult` or any class derived from it things should just work).

Comment: @marcind I get a Stack Overflow on w3wp.exe if I set the return type to `ActionResult`. Works fine if the return type is `PartialViewResult`. Think I need to file a Connect bug?

Comment: Does sound like one to me - do shout back if you submit a Connect bug, will vote it up.