# Why is _PageStart.cshtml not being run before rendering a partial view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have _PageStart.cshtml in /View/ (so it's path is ~/View/_PageStart.cshtml)

During debugging, none of the breakpoints set in _PageStart are being hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By convention, file name should be `_ViewStart.cshtml` in asp.net MVC view folder. It is similar as `_PageStart.cshtml` in asp.net web form.

And if you return PartialView() from your controllers (instead of return View()), then _viewstart.cshtml will not be executed. [ [Correct way to use _viewstart.cshtml and partial Razor views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081811/correct-way-to-use-viewstart-cshtml-and-partial-razor-views) ]