# How to override the layout defined in _ViewStart for certain views in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to suppress the layout expressed in `_ViewStart.cshtml` using ASP.NET MVC 3 for certain views of an app.

I understand that I can define the layout programmatically in the controller action. Maybe passing in `""` achieves that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*You have two options*

1) Use `return PartialView()` from controller, it won't take Layout from View start

2) Assign Layout = null,

```
 @{
     Layout = null;
  }
```

Check-out this interesting discussion and answer by marcind around this [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081811/correct-way-to-use-viewstart-cshtml-and-partial-razor-views/4082220#4082220)

Comment: Can you also overwrite it with another layout? I'm on a specific page and I want to say `Layout = "Other layout than the one in view start"` ?  Will it work?

Answer (score 3):

In order not to apply a layout, just assign null to the Layout property in your view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

Comment: Thanks. razor code like this: Layout = "" seems to work as well (just figured this out before you posted answer). is null better you reckon?

Comment: Thanks. I have to say that I prefer the retun of partial views.

Comment: @csetzkorn – why do you prefer partial views?