# (Nancy) Razor View Engine partial view rendering full HTML

Tags: razor, partial-views, nancy

Using Nancy and the Razor view engine I get the following situation.
I have a view:

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @Html.Partial("_PartialPage1")
    </body>
</html>
```

And a partial view containing:

```
   <strong>I am partial.</strong>
```

After running the application generated HTML looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>


<strong>I am partial.</strong>

</body>
</html>

</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems as if the partial is rendered as a full HTML page instead of the snippet. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

EDIT: I am using Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.

UPDATE: I am using a _ViewStart.cshtml which seems to be applied to the partial view as well. Can this be prevented?

UPDATE:
Files in the views folder

```
Views
  Default
    _ViewStart.cshtml
    Index.cshtml
  Partials
    _PartialPage.cshtml
  Shared
    _LayoutPage.cshtml
```

_ViewStart.cshtml contains the reference to the Layoutpage to be used.

```
@{
  Layout = "Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}
```

The problem is that it is applied to the _PartialPage.cshtml as well. Independant of which folder the _ViewStart.cshtml is placed.
I hope you can reproduce it like this.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, but I'll be looking at upgrading Nancy to Razor 3.0 this weekend so will take another look. If you can create a reproducible project that would be awesome to help fix it.

Comment: Not sure how to upload a sample project.

Comment: throw something up on Github, or dropbox, or pop into Jabbr Nancy room and I can give you my email. https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/nancyfx

Comment: A test project is available at: https://github.com/frankjwitte/NancyRazorPartial

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I will pull it tonight and take a look.

Comment: I guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081811/correct-way-to-use-viewstart-cshtml-and-partial-razor-views is a related question. 
Only, I do not see how the solution given there would be achieved with Nancy.

Comment: looks like this is a bug, MVC seems to differ on the view returned but in Nancy we don't, so the magic of a Start View ends up being rendered all the time :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in short, when using Nancy/Razor de _ViewStart.cshtml is applied to all views, even partial views.
Thank you Phill for clearing that up.

Comment: I've fixed this, sending a PR in an hour or so, so hopefully will be in Nancy 0.22.0. Thanks for finding the issue.