# How do I avoid calling the MVC _ViewStart for one page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout

I need to call the _ViewStart layout page for every page exept one.

How do I skip it for just one page (let's call it a.cshtml)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source SO

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081811/correct-way-to-use-viewstart-cshtml-and-partial-razor-views) by [marcind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358970/marcind)

If you return `PartialView()` from your controllers (instead of return `View()`), then `_viewstart.cshtml` will not be executed.

Answer (score 7):

You can just add this to the top of the page you don't want to use the layout for.

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
```